# Observable.interval() - How can I resume the interval if network call fails?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an `Observable.interval()` that I'm using an SDK to poll an API endpoint every 5 seconds.

So that means when I make the network call, there is a chance that it throws an error.

(usually the first 3 calls)

This causes my `Observable.interval()` to execute once and no longer to continue to run.

How can I have the interval, catch the error, and also continue to run even if an error is thrown?

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    return remoteRepository.performFirstQuery();
})
     .flatMapObservable(txHash -> {
         //I want to poll with the txHash every 5 seconds until there is no error
         return Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .map(n -> {
                 return remoteRepository.performSecondQuery(txHash).execute();
               });
     })
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(txResult -> {

     }, err -> {

     });
```

**Edit:___________________________________________**

I tried adding `.onErrorResumeNext()` like RAI's suggestion, but after one error happens, the observable interval is no longer being fired.

```
.flatMapObservable(txHash -> {
      return Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .map(n -> {
             return remoteRepository.performSecondQuery(txHash).execute();
       }).onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
            //This is error block is called, but only called once
            return Observable.empty();
      });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why RAI deleted his accepted answer, but adding

`.repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));`

Worked for me

```
.flatMapObservable(txHash -> {
      return Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .map(n -> {
             return remoteRepository.performSecondQuery(txHash).execute();
       })
      .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
            return Observable.empty();
      })
      .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));;
})
```

Comment: due to the moderator, my answer was deleted for no reason and wasn't restored after the investigation. Thank you for writing the proper solution for others